# Webhook execution error: Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 400 missing_text_or_fallback_or_attachments

Tags: gitlab, slack

I am trying to integrate Slack with GitLab.

- I installed a webhook in slack and copied the webhook url to GitLab's app integration.
- I have also enabled the Slack integration in GitLab's integration setting.

> However I keep getting the error:

```
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 400 missing_text_or_fallback_or_attachments
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 9):

This is currently followed by [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 41853](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/41853)

It includes:

> Don't use the Integration part.. read further.
>
> Use Slack Notifications what's in the end of Project services if you scroll down on the `Project > Settings > Integration` page.

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/uploads/56ed3353dea919d1ccb8e337500e81d1/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA.PNG]

But even that does not seem to be always enough (it appears to [work in the OP's case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069769/webhook-execution-error-hook-executed-successfully-but-returned-http-400-missin/60070358#comment106240416_60070358)).
Check if you see any stack trace in `sudo gitlab-ctl tail`.